# How to make a property injection via @Value annotation mandatory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I have the following Test.java POJO class being populated from a property file using the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation. I have seen the usage of `@Required` annotation to make it a mandatory.

Rather than defining annotations at the setter method level, are there any annotations or options within the `@Value` annotation that I can use for defining conditions like Mandatory, NotNull, etc?

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.test")
public class Test {
  private String name;

  @Required
  public void setName(String name) {
    name = name;
  }

  public String getName(String name) {
    name = name;
  }
}
```

Is this the right and only way for making a particular attribute mandatory? What are the other such annotations I could use for such conditions or validations purpose?

Comment: not sure about spring but if you are willing to dirty your pojo with hibernate  then its possible - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/  or you could create a custom annotation. refer to https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303

Answer (score 3):

You can use validation for the properties, just not in the way you envisaged.
What you can do is use standard validation annotations (like `@NotNull` etc.) on the fields (or setters) themselves.

For example

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=10)
private String name;
```

Check out [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-validation) part of the documentation

What the documentation essentially says, is that you simply have to have a compatible JSR303 validator implementation on the classpath, and use the relevant annotations. 
Spring Boot will take care of the rest

Comment: But the questioner is asking: *Rather than defining annotations at the setter method level*, are there any annotations or options within the @Value annotation that I can use for defining conditions like Mandatory, NotNull, etc?"

Comment: @AndrewSpencer You're correct, I need to clarify the answer

Answer (score 1):

According to the Spring [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) (currently 4.1.6.RELEASE), the `Value` annotation only has a single property, `value`, containing the value of the property. You can put a Spring EL expression in this, but that won't let you explicitly express notions like non-nullity.

Further, in your code snippet you're using `@ConfigurationProperties` which is an alternative approach to configuring property values, compared to the `@Value` annotation.

The way you're doing it, your Java getter/setter names need to map to the property names, i.e. prefix "com.test" + `getName()` / `setName()` matches property `com.test.name=...`
So, you don't need the `@Value` annotation to tell Spring what property to use.

With the `@Value` approach, your getters/setters don't have to match the property names, but you do have to annotate each property e.g. `@Value("${com.test.name}")` and on the class, a `@PropertySource` annotation pointing to the properties file that contains `com.test.name=...`

I found a couple of blog posts with code examples that use the 2 different ways to inject the same properties: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/09/using-configurationproperties-in-spring.html and http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/09/testing-mail-code-in-spring-boot.html